# Is it a bad idea to make some service configurable by a callable?

Tags: php, symfony, oop, design-patterns

It's common for many frameworks to have classes that can accept configuration parameters from an array, but why arrays, if we may use closures or invokable classes?

For example some router service:

```
class Router 
{
    public function __construct(Closure $config)
    {
        $closure($this);
    }

    public function addRoute(...$params) {
        // some code
    }
}
```

config/router.php:

```
return function($router) {

    $router
        ->addRoute('/')
        ->setName('home')
    ;

    // and so on....        
}
```

Then somewhere:

```
$router = new Router(include 'config/router.php');
$controller = $router->match('/some/path');
```

Am I missing something? Maybe I'm not experienced enough, but I haven't seen this approach yet.

UPD: To illustrate my point better, here is an updated version:

```
class Router 
{
    public function configureWith(callable $configurator)
    {
        $configurator($this);
        return $this;
    }

    public function addRoute(...$params) {
        // some code
    }
}


class RouterConfigurator 
{
    public function __invoke($router)
    {
        $router->addRoute('/');
        $router->addRoute('/some');

        // and so on....  
    }
}


$router = new Router;
$router->configureWith(new RouterConfigurator);
$controller = $router->match('/some/path');
```

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, there could be a myriad of reasons, but probably the main one for me is readability. Closures are fine and have their place, but they can make the ability to quickly read code and debug it a nightmare.

Arrays on the other hand are simple, lightweight and all the code that processes them is in the object (encapsulation).

A lot of programmers could learn a lot and generate easier to read code if they followed the KISS principle and didn't get off on writing 'funky' code.

Remember, someone else may have to maintain your code after you and/or you may need to remember what you coded when you come back 6/12 months after you wrote it. What made sense back then may seem alien to you later!

Not to mention in your particular example, if you later add code to add additional functionality, all of your initialisation code for that object is littered through the code.

Comment: IMO this approach is simpler, and more performant than parsing a static array. And for me is more readable, but this is debatable, of course.

Comment: But for every instance you create, you'd be creating closures to configure them.. that's going to lead to duplicated code and really breaks the Encapsulation rule of OOP as far as I'm concerned. 

But as you say, its debatable and at the end of the day, do what you feel is right. But for everyone else, there's something to be said by the fact that no one else uses closures to initialise classes! Usually when an implementation is consistent across frameworks, there's a very good reason why.

Comment: please, check my updated question. Closures was just to illustrate callable object. Generally, I'm taking about reusable standalone components that has no external dependencies, but need to be configured before usage. Something like Aura for PHP.

Comment: tbh, it still seems to be overcomplicating something that can be done a lot simpler. But it sounds like you're familiar with this pattern, hence why it makes sense to you. To me it makes more sense to have the code to set up the Router within the router class itself, rather than injecting a configuration object which then does the configuration.